# Cloud9 installation issue

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to install Cloud9 on my web server via tutorial, but I got some trouble.
When I'm trying to run command *node bin/cloud9.js* i get:

djent@server:~/ide$ node bin/cloud9.js

```
node.js:216
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: require.paths is removed. Use node_modules folders, or the NODE_PATH environment variable instead.
    at Function.<anonymous> (module.js:381:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/djent/ide/support/paths.js:7:8)
    at Module.<anonymous> (module.js:444:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:462:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:32)
    at Function._load (module.js:309:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:373:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/djent/ide/bin/cloud9.js:6:1)
    at Module.<anonymous> (module.js:444:26)
djent@server:~/ide$
```

How to fix it? I've tried to reinstall node but it's not working.

Comment: This problem is answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558865/error-require-paths-is-removed-when-running-node-js-socket-io

Comment: it's not about that module, and link to solution is dead

Answer (score 1):

Try to start in with bin/cloud9.sh script. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud9 doesn't run under nodejs 0.6 at the moment. Use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to switch to node 0.4.12 to run Cloud9.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install all the required library packages like

```
libxml2-dev
```

which are given in the requirements section of the given link

https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9?source=c